# Is print job data stored locally or on the server side when I use a Windows print server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, printing, print-server

I have read [Why use a print server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/569644/why-use-a-print-server) and it does not indicate the location of print job data.

When I restarted the local printer service today to fix a problem with a stuck job, all jobs disappeared (not only the stuck job). I assume that documents are stored in a local file and wait there for processing. Is this correct?

Comment: No, they're sent to the print server where they sit waiting to be processed. Next time open the print queue on the affected printer on the print server and cancel the stuck job rather than cycling the service.